# Apache Directory Index showing files but not folders with mod_auth_openidc

Tags: apache, directory, debian, virtualhost, mod-auth-openidc

I have a folder with files and folders inside it and I am running **Apache 2.4** on **Debian Jessie**.
Everything is `chmoded 755` and `chowned by www-data`.

I have enabled Directory Indexing with `Options +Indexes` and also with `Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews` from the  config of my VirtualHost.

I have no `IndexIgnore` directive in the `apache2.conf`

**When I access the folder from HTTP, Apache only shows the files but not the folders.**

I'd like to show the folder links as well. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Just for sake of testing, add `IndexIgnoreReset ON` to `.htaccess` file and see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like mod_auth_openidc did not want Apache to list folders for some reason.
I overrode that with:

```
IndexOptions +ShowForbidden
```

Comment: Disabling it fixed also the issue

Comment: ok, this does seem to be an issue that needs to be addressed in the module

Comment: and so it was done: https://github.com/pingidentity/mod_auth_openidc/commit/daeb8606a79c949d6a9af46357d21c0037bf47f5